# How to order the result of SQLite query by input alphabet?

Tags: android, sqlite

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME +
                " WHERE " + ENGLISH + " LIKE ? ORDER BY " + ENGLISH + " LIMIT 100";

try {
            cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, new String[]{"%" + englishWord + "%"});
```

For example, in the column `ENGLISH`, there are "ice", "dice", "vice" etc. When I input the word "ice" in `englishWord`, I will get the result arranged firstly by "dice", followed by "ice" and "vice". But I would like "ice" to be on the first order because it has the exact word. How I can accomplish this?

Comment: And if the user enters "vice"? you want `vice` before `dice` and `ice`?

Comment: Yes, exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `LENGTH` Function to get Exact Matched Phrase , This Should be your Query

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME +
                " WHERE " + ENGLISH + " LIKE ? ORDER BY LENGTH(" + ENGLISH + ") LIMIT 100";
```

Comment: You mean `LENGTH`, not `LEN`.

Answer (score 0):

To order exact matches first, add another ORDER BY expression that returns a smaller number for exact matches:

```java
rawQuery("... ORDER BY "+ENGLISH+" != ?, "+ENGLISH+"...",
         new String[]{ "%"+englishWord+"%", englishWord });
```

`English != ?` is a boolean expression; it returns either 0 or 1.